# Prove $ (\tan(x))^{'} = \frac{1}{\cos^2(x)} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I want to prove $\displaystyle (\tan (x))'=\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)} $ using the definition of the derivative. So I started with the following:\begin{align*}\lim \limits _{h\to 0}\frac{\tan (x+h)-\tan (x)}{h} & =\lim \limits _{h\to 0}\frac{\sin (x+h-x)}{\cos (x+h)\cos (x)} \\
& =\lim \limits _{h\to 0}\frac{\sin (h)}{\cos (x+h)\cos (x)}.
\end{align*}But the problem is that $\lim \limits _{h\to 0}\sin (h)=0\neq 1$. Can you give me a hint on how to solve this?

I know there are other identities for tan(x + h) - tan(x), but I want to solve this problem using the on I wrote in the solution.

Comment: No, you missed $1/h$, and the limit of $sin(h)/h$ is $1$ for $h\to 0$

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 5):

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\tan(x + h) - \tan(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin(x + h - x)}{h\cos(x + h)\cos(x)} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin(h)}{h\cos(x + h)\cos(x)}=\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}$$

because $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(h)}{h}=1$.

Answer (score 0):

From the trig identity $\tan(A-B)=\frac{\tan A - \tan B}{1+\tan A \tan B}$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\tan(x+h)-\tan(x)}{h}&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\tan(x+h-x)(1+\tan(x)\tan(x+h))}{h}\\ 
&= \left(\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\tan h}{h}\right)\left(\lim_{h\to 0}\, 1+\tan x \tan(x+h)\right) \\
&= (1)(1+\tan^2x)=\sec^2x.
\end{align}$$